# ASP RadioButton behaves differently(see: broken) with and without tooltip text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

So I have run into quite a perplexing issue where using an ASP RadioButton behaves dramatically differently with the presence and absence of a tooltip or tooltip text. The radiobuttons cannot hold a checked state, you can click back and forth all day, it will temporarily show as checked in the ui and serverside(checkedchanged will say one is checked), but then immediately afterwards both radiobuttons are considered unchecked in the ui and serverside(clicking the not shown "generate export" button for example). It will not behave as a radiobutton, but more as a standard button with a postback, nothing radio about it, and they both look unchecked from the ui.

Relevant snipits:

Broken:

```
    <asp:RadioButton ID="ui_assetExport0" runat="server" GroupName="assetExport" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" Text="By Filter" ToolTip="" />

    <asp:RadioButton ID="ui_assetExport1" runat="server" GroupName="assetExport" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" Text="By Category" ToolTip="" />

    <input id="ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_ui_assetExport0" type="radio" name="ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$assetExport" value="ui_assetExport0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$ui_assetExport0\',\'\')', 0)">

    <input id="ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_ui_assetExport1" type="radio" name="ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$assetExport" value="ui_assetExport1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$ui_assetExport1\',\'\')', 0)">
```

(Note: this exact behavior is present when the tooltip is removed completely)

Working:

```
    <asp:RadioButton ID="ui_assetExport0" runat="server" GroupName="assetExport" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" Text="By Filter" ToolTip=" " />

    <asp:RadioButton ID="ui_assetExport1" runat="server" GroupName="assetExport" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" Text="By Category" ToolTip=" " />

    <input id="ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_ui_assetExport0" type="radio" name="ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$assetExport" value="ui_assetExport0" checked="checked">

    <input id="ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_ui_assetExport1" type="radio" name="ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$assetExport" value="ui_assetExport1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContentPlaceHolder$ui_assetExport1\',\'\')', 0)">
```

(Note: there is nothing but a blank space in the tooltips, but the behavior is the same if something is there)

For the first pair they both have an onclick javascript postback, vs the second pair which has the checked property for the selected radiobutton instead(choosing one or the other will swap which has the onclick and checked property as expected).

Some other strange behavior was also observed with these tooltips which was that when there was a decent bit of text in it, the tooltip of the first radiobutton would show immediately upon opening the dialog(even though I was explicitly placing focus on a different control in the dialog open function and not hovering over the radiobutton), and said tooltip remains there permanently until the page is refreshed(~75% of the time it would be permanent. Postbacks, clicking other controls/areas, hovering over for other tooltips, closing the dialog, etc did not clear the tooltip). The first radiobutton is the first control in the dialog as well if that helps.

The broken radiobuttons seem to be doing their job as radiobuttons properly serverside in the checkedchanged events, but when the "generate export" button is clicked both radiobuttons are considered unchecked.

A bit more relavent information might be that these controls are in a JQuery v1.11.2(yes yes, I know) Modal Dialog, and inside of an ASP UpdatePanel inside of the dialog. Also yes, as crazy as it sounds, the tooltip text is literally the only difference made between working and broken radiobuttons. There are no javascript errors on the page, and no code at all runs after the checkedchanged event (which shows them looking like they are working) when stepping through the code. There is also no javascript that touches these controls or their properties whatsoever in the page.

Does anyone have an idea of why the presence/absence of tooltip text(or the tooltip itself) changes the behavior of the radiobuttons so severely, and why the tooltip shows regardless of focus and stays permanently?

Sorry for the wall of text, was trying to be as descriptive and accurate as I could since this behavior is quite bizarre.

Comment: this looks like asp.net, not asp-classic as you have it tagged.

Comment: thanks, corrected the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into problems with RadioButtons with the AutoPostBack set to true when inside of UpdatePanels, and although the problems I have had are not related to the ToolTip it does sound somewhat similar and I think worthy of suggesting.

I have worked around this issue by adding my own onclick attribute to each RadioButton to ensure that it can post back, eg:

```
ui_assetExport0.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'" + ui_assetExport0.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") + "\',\'\')', 0)");
```

(Won't help your stuck tooltip issue though)

It may help if you posted more of your code, in particular the structure relating to UpdatePanel(s).